# How can I access the value of elements nested deeply within several objects and arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, google-maps, data-structures

I'm making an API call to return data from the Google Distance Matrix API and saving that data in my (react)redux store.

The data object being returned is structured like this:

```
Object {
  "destination_addresses": Array [
    "21 Foo St, SomeCity, SomeState 33333, USA",
  ],
  "origin_addresses": Array [
    "5555 Somewhere Dr, Somewhere, Somewhere 55555, USA",
  ],
  "rows": Array [
    Object {
      "elements": Array [
        Object {
          "distance": Object {
            "text": "2,302 mi",
            "value": 3703935,
          },
          "duration": Object {
            "text": "1 day 10 hours",
            "value": 123162,
          },
          "status": "OK",
         },
      ],
    },
  ],
  "status": "OK",
}
```

That data structure is returned when I `console.log(this.props.matrixData)`.

I need to access distance.text & duration.text so that I can display them on a component screen.

I made several different failed attempts like

```
this.props.matrixData.rows.elements.distance.text
```

and

```
this.props.matrixData.rows[0].elements[0]
```

etc to access deeper, but `this.props.matrixData.rows` is the deepest I've been able to get without throwing an error.

Can someone help please?

Comment: If that's your data structure `this.props.matrixData.rows[0].elements[0]` should work unless the data isn't uniform and something is undefined. What error do you get? Also, `this.props.matrixData.rows.elements.distance.text ` will never work because you haven't specified what element in rows to access.

Comment: With `this.props.matrixData.rows[0].elements[0]` the error thrown is `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.matrixData.rows[0]')`. Also yeah I had a feeling the whole `rows.elements.distance.text` thing wouldn't work but I'm just so confused I've even tried the things that don't make any sense out of frustration haha

Comment: It sounds like the answer should work for you, but if it's saying it's not an object I would be concerned that your data model may not be accurate..

Comment: Super weird!! This is the data structure that is returned from the (successful) API call so I don't know why it wouldn't be accurate. Maybe something to do with how I'm processing the data after it's been returned. I'll go back and look.

Comment: That would be the next thing that I would check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your example in the (Chrome) browser console, but I left out the "type annotations". Your second example for access works for me, I am not sure why it would fail.

```
var o = {
"destination_addresses": [
    "21 Foo St, SomeCity, SomeState 33333, USA",
],
"origin_addresses": [
    "5555 Somewhere Dr, Somewhere, Somewhere 55555, USA",
],
"rows": [
    {
    "elements": [
        {
        "distance": {
            "text": "2,302 mi",
            "value": 3703935,
        },
        "duration": {
            "text": "1 day 10 hours",
            "value": 123162,
        },
        "status": "OK",
        },
    ],
    },
],
"status": "OK",
};
o.rows[0].elements[0]; // logs "Object { distance: {…}, duration: {…}, status: "OK" }"
```

Please note that `o.rows[0].elements[0]` will throw an error if one of the Arrays is empty. There are libraries which fail gracefully in such cases:

- https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path, see also an [example of Ramda path](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.25.0#?R.path%28%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%5D%2C%20%7Ba%3A%20%7Bb%3A%202%7D%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%202%0AR.path%28%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%5D%2C%20%7Bc%3A%20%7Bb%3A%202%7D%7D%29%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20undefined%0A%0Avar%20o%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20destination_addresses%3A%20%5B%2221%20Foo%20St%2C%20SomeCity%2C%20SomeState%2033333%2C%20USA%22%5D%2C%0A%20%20origin_addresses%3A%20%5B%225555%20Somewhere%20Dr%2C%20Somewhere%2C%20Somewhere%2055555%2C%20USA%22%5D%2C%0A%20%20rows%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20elements%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20distance%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%222%2C302%20mi%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%203703935%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20duration%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20%221%20day%2010%20hours%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%20123162%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20status%3A%20%22OK%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20status%3A%20%22OK%22%0A%7D%3B%0AR.path%28%5B%27rows%27%2C%20%270%27%2C%20%27elements%27%2C%20%270%27%5D%2C%20o%29%3B)
- https://lodash.com/docs/#get

Comment: You could use a library, but a simple `&&` check will return false if an item doesn't exist. a.e.  `o && o.rows && o.rows[0] && o.rows[0].elements && o.rows[0].elements[0]`    - it seems like a lot, but it's not compared to bringing in an entire library to take care of it. In addition if you utilize it with an `||` you can provide a default value like an empty object in case of failure: `o && o.rows && o.rows[0] && o.rows[0].elements && o.rows[0].elements[0] || {}`

Comment: I'm not sure why it's failing either :/  The error I get is `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.matrixData.rows[0]')` but none of the arrays are empty

Comment: Update: you guys were right, o.rows[0].elements[0] was the correct way to target the values. The problem was my method of passing the data.

The arrays were in fact showing "empty" on the initial rendering of the app screen due to how the data was being retrieved. Since the data wasn't immediately ready on initialization, the "empty" arrays were throwing the error like @pipereset mentioned.  I changed my method of saving/retrieving the data so it'd be available before even loading the screen and it works now. Thank you!!